# GetGlobalResourceObject exception handling

Tags: c#

I have a project that makes extensive use of the GetGlobalResourceObject  which is a member of the System.Web.UI class. It works fine providing english or french labels to the bilingual C#/ASP.NET application.

But....if the reference in the resource file is missing or malformed the application crashes

There are hundreds of calls like this

GetGlobalResourceObject("XXX.WebResource", "Remove")

Is there any way to encapsulate the GetGlobalResourceObject with an exception handler so that it returns null and logs it if there's a problem without adding a try/catch to each call?

I am new to C# so I don't know if I can override the GetGlobalResourceObject with my own class and then do a search and replace.  Surely there is a better way.

Kevinsky

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own version of `GetGlobalResourceObject` to embed the exception handling and logging in that:

```
public static Object MyGetGlobalResourceObject (string classKey,
                                                string resourceKey)
{
    try
    {
        return GetGlobalResourceObject (classKey, resourceKey);
    }
    catch (MissingManifestResourceException ex)
    {
        // log error
        return null;
    }
}
```

*This code is provided as an starting point*

You could even write it as an extension method on `HttpContext`.

You will have to do a global search and replace to call this rather than the base method, which isn't the most elegant solution, but it will work.